# Determining all possible values of contour integral of $\int\exp{z^{-1}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

In our class, we are asked to find all possible values of $\int_{\gamma}\exp{z^{-1}}dz$ where $\gamma$ is any closed curve not passing through $z=0$.

I wanted to ask if I can rewrite this expression so that I can easily determine the poles of $f\left(z\right)=\exp z^{-1}$, so that I can use residues to solve for the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:** It is clear the only singularity is at zero, so all matters is how many times the curve winds around 0. Substitute $\frac{1}{z}$ into the power series for $e^z$ to compute the residue there.